# MariaDb/MySQL sliding sum over 24 hours

Tags: mysql, mariadb, window-functions, sliding-window

My table have fields that represent starting and ending working period as datetime.

I need to find related entries that match a total of 14hours min over a sliding period of 24 hours.

I think window function will (maybe) save me, but MariadDB (i use) doesn't implement yet Range time intervals in window function.

here is some example data:

```
id  starting_hour        ending_hour          
--  -------------------  -------------------
 1  2018-09-02 06:00:00  2018-09-02 08:30:00  
 2  2018-09-03 08:30:00  2018-09-03 10:00:00  
 4  2018-09-03 11:00:00  2018-09-03 15:00:00  
 5  2018-09-02 15:30:00  2018-09-02 16:00:00  
 6  2018-09-02 16:15:00  2018-09-02 17:00:00  
 7  2018-09-20 00:00:00  2018-09-20 08:00:00  
 8  2018-09-19 10:00:00  2018-09-19 12:00:00  
 9  2018-09-19 12:00:00  2018-09-19 16:00:00  
10  2018-10-08 12:00:00  2018-10-08 14:00:00  
11  2018-10-29 09:00:00  2018-10-29 10:00:00
```

So how to find rows where in a 24 hours window their sum a more or equal to 14 hours.

thanks

Edit:

```
SELECT
  id,
  starting_hour,
  ending_hour,
  TIMEDIFF (ending_hour, starting_hour) AS duree,
  (
SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(LEAST(ending_hour, DATE_ADD(a.starting_hour, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)), starting_hour)) / 10000
FROM `table` b
WHERE b.starting_hour BETWEEN a.starting_hour AND DATE_ADD(a.starting_hour, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
  ) AS duration              
FROM
  `table` a
HAVING duration >= 14
ORDER BY starting_hour ASC
 ;
```

This returns Id 8 but i want the whole period. (eg: Id 8, Id 9 and Id 7)

EDIT2:

The expected results are ranges of working time where they are in a window of 24 hours and where their sum are more or equal to 14 hours.

EDIT 3:
In fact under MySQL 8 this seems to work.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
  *,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hs.`ending_hour`, hs.`starting_hour`))) OVER (ORDER BY hs.starting_hour RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '12' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '12' HOUR following)) AS tot
FROM
  table hs
  WHERE hs.`starting_hour` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND hs.`ending_hour` <= NOW()
 ORDER BY hs.`starting_hour` ASC
 ) t1
  HAVING tot >= '14:00:00' 
 ;
```

Is there a way to do it under MariaDB 10.2 without window function ? Or without window range function ?

Comment: Question is bit unclear! What is expected output as per your given sample data ?

Comment: What defines 24 hours? Start - Start or Start - End?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but without window functions, you're probably going to need a bufugly query.

Comment: I want to find the entries that represent a total of 14 hours (or more) over a sliding window of 24 hours. Is it clearer ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i think window function can be the solution, but in fact MariaDB doesn't implement _DATE RANGE INTERVAL_ [MDEV-9727](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9727?jql=project%20%3D%20MDEV%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Optimizer%20-%20Window%20functions%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22range%20time%22)

Comment: @SalmanA 24 hours _IS_ the sliding window the sum is **start + end**

Comment: I don't see why you don't use simple self-join. Just select all 24h intervals as one dataset and join into it all fitting intervals with 14h - or am I missing something?

Comment: Why not, any example ?